# Windows 8.1 not coming up in boot options?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader

So I made a 200gb partition out of my 2tb HDD for ubuntu 14.04.1 and followed ALL the instructions listed in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU

Yet when I reboot I only get the options

"Ubuntu something something"
and
"Advanced options for ubuntu"
Is there a way to boot into windows again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you installed Ubuntu with legacy support. I know this, because the tool he used to create the USB specifically says that it will install an MBR. MBR doesn't work in EFI systems. So, more than likely you had to change an EFI/BIOS setting in order to get the USB to boot in the first place. This setting is usually called Legacy Boot or CSM in the EFI setup. If Ubuntu is installed this way, then it will only boot from legacy mode and, hence, GRUB cannot boot Windows 8 -- because Windows 8 requires it to be in EFI mode (in most cases, like if the computer shipped with Windows 8). If your computer did not ship with Windows 8, then you're going to have to determine somehow whether you have EFI or not. I'm not entirely sure how to do that from Windows.

How do you fix this? Or, how to convert Ubuntu to EFI boot.

1. Boot Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
3. `sudo apt-get install grub-efi linux-signed-image-generic`
4. Just to be sure, run the command `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot and enter the EFI setup
6. Change back to regular boot mode (non-Legacy/CSM)
7. Go ahead and set 'Ubuntu' as your boot option (under the Boot tab usually) while you're there

After that, you should be up and running.

In the future, write the ISO directly to the USB using a tool such as [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) or [Win32 Disk Imager](http://www.askvg.com/win32-disk-imager-write-any-bootable-image-to-usb-drive-in-windows/) (it says it doesn't work with ISO files, but in this particular case you could rename the .iso to .img and it should work just fine).

Comment: I got this when I pasted that into the terminal "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
"

Comment: Disregard the last comment. Typed sudo update-grub than restarted and disabled efi boot. I can now boot into windows and linux perfectly!. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer helped you out, be sure to hit that 'best answer' button =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix your boot isses.
Just burn the image to a cd/dvd or make a bootable usb thumbdrive, boot from it and click recommended repair.